# MySQL import records and shift primary key increment

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains the columns **id**, **created_date**, and **name**, where id is the auto-incremented primary key (starting at 1) and created_date is the date the row was created (just an example).

There are 50 rows in this table since the launch of this application. Suppose I have 100 old records (considering the created_date values) that I want to import into this table.

Is there a simple way to shift the id values of the current records to 101-150, so I can import the old records with id values of 1-100? Is this even advisable?

If I had to do it over again, I would've adjusted up the auto-increment of the id column (primary key) before launching the application to accommodate the records I intended to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could renumber them with an `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE table SET id = id + 100;
```

Or import them into a new table which has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value pre-set:

```
 CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101;
```

You'll need to take care to ensure that you maintain referential integrity - if other tables reference this table, then you'll need to make sure that they are updated too.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but I wouldn't advise shifting primary keys on a production table. This would kill referential integrity by breaking your data associations.

Answer (score 0):

1.`update table1 set id = id+100`. Make sure that you changed all references to these records in other tables(it will be done automatically if you use foreign keys with `on update cascade` option.
2. insert 100 old records
3. update auto-increment of the id